# Can I append a img to a img

Tags: jquery, tags, append, image

So I tried out if I can append using jquery a image to an image and it works, but the image seems to be gone or visibility is hidden and display none or so it seems.

So my question is can this be done and can I use this image. Its for a project I am working on.

```
<img src="img/map.png" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; z-index: -100;">

    <img src="img/dot.png" style="position: relative; width: 20px; 
         height:34px; top: 200px; left: 200px; z-index: 100; 
        display: block; visibility: visible;">

</img>
```

thats what my code looks like after I use the append. and if you look at it in firebug you see that the child img looks like it is not displayed so I tried changing the visibility but still not luck.

so my question is can this be done or am I after the unattainable.

Comment: img tags are 'self closing tags: `<img src="" alt=""/>` so you cannot use </img> to close something that is NOT closeable any more. Rather tell us what are you trying to achieve. Does the first image have to disappear? or? (before jumping to JS / jQuery... do your homework on HTML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.2) the `<img>` element cannot have content:

> The IMG element has no content; it is
>   usually replaced inline by the image
>   designated by the src attribute, the
>   exception being for left or
>   right-aligned images that are
>   "floated" out of line.

So trying to nest `<img>` tags would result into undefined behavior.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use append, use [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) so that the second image goes after the first, not inside it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid HTML. You can append an `<img>` as a *sibling* to another, but you shouldn't do it within an existing image.

To append after:

```
$(imageSelector).after('<img ... />'); // method 1
$('<img ... />').insertAfter(imageSelector); // method 2
```

or before:

```
$(imageSelector).before('<img ... />'); // method 1
$('<img ... />').insertBefore(imageSelector); // method 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I couldnt find the answer anywhere

Answer (score 0):

It's unattainable but not for the reasons given in the other answers. Although `img` is a void element and therefore *should not* contain content, and in the HTML serialization, the parser will never place content inside an `img` element, as you have discovered, it is *possible* for an `img` element to gain content through scripting.

It is also possible for an `img` element to have content if it parsed using an XML parser, as happens if you serve XHTML with an XML content type such as application/xhtml+xml

For these reasons, the situation is **not undefined** in HTML5. The text for [the img element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element) says:

> The contents of img elements, if any,
>   are ignored for the purposes of
>   rendering.

So adding the element as a sibling instead, as given in the other answers, is the correct resolution.